# Make Firebase Recycler expandable (custom Adapter)

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have tried for days to implement the option of clicking on a item (that is populated with firebase data) expands, like the what the following [lib 1](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/ExpandableLayout) and [lib 2](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) allow, I also have tried to add the following 'native' solution to the onBindViewHolder method, but nothing works because I can't seem to have access to this method when I create a custom adapter that extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

```
final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
holder.details.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Here's the current code for that

```
    private RecyclerView mPostRV;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> mPostAdapter;
private DatabaseReference mPostRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_main);

    initialiseScreen();

}


private void initialiseScreen() {
    mPostRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_rv);
    mPostRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FoodMain.this));
    mPostRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FOODS);
    setupAdapter();
    mPostRV.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
}

private void setupAdapter() {

    mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.item_layout_post,
            PostViewHolder.class,
            mPostRef
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, int position) {

            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(model.getImageUrl());
            Glide.with(FoodMain.this)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(storageReference)
                    .into(viewHolder.postIV);

            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setPhone(model.getPhone());



        }
    };


}
```

Thanks

Comment: There are only ~6 classes inside FirebaseUI for Database Adapters, so just copy paste them into your own project and you can access whatever methods you need as you'll have control over access.
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database

Comment: I thought of it, but copying within Android Studio kept the protection, now that you mentioned it I did from outside and modified the classes as I wished. Thanks